# math equation project

Tags: java

```
public class problem1 {
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
    int [] a = new int [1000];

    for (int counter = 0; counter<=a.length;counter++);
    { 
        if ((counter % 3 == 0) || (counter % 5 == 0))
        {
            int temp += counter;
        }
    }

}
}
```

I am trying to solve an equation where you have to go through an array with the numbers 1-1000, and add up all of the numbers that are multiples of 3 and 5, but my code wont execute. Can anyone see my error?

Comment: You need to use a debugger.

Comment: What is the use of 'a'?

Comment: This question reads like I'm being quizzed.

Comment: you dont need an array and you keep redeclaring temp in the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Your code has two major problems:

- You have a semi-colon at the end of your for loop.

  ```
  for (int counter = 0; counter<=a.length;counter++); // Remove the ;
  ```
- You are re-declaring your variable each time in your for loop.

  ```
  int temp += counter;  // replace it with `temp += counter`.
  ```

And declare the variable `temp` outside the `for loop`, with it's default value `0`.

And a minor problem is:

- You don't need that array  `a`. Rather declare an `int` variable say `total` with the required value (in this case, `1000`). And use it in loop condition, rather than `a.length`.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not create an array for your counter. It is not necessary, arrays usually store reusable values such as names, cities, ages etc. basically.
- Also for loop does not ends with semi-colon.
- Most important: Not declare a variable in a loop. If you do it you will create X times variable again and again

```
public class problem1 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)

    {
        if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0)) {
            temp += i;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Result is :" + temp);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never execute because of the semi-colon at the end of your for, it won't give you compilation error, but it means an empty statement, so the for body will never be executed, just remove the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should initialize `int temp` outside the for loop first. It should be as follows: `int temp = 0;` and then `temp += counter;` should work.